# Ad Preview Facebook for all ads under account ID

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

How can I get Ad preview of all ads under my Ad account using PHP.

The FB ad preview plugin is deprecated (Code Below)

**`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/ad-preview-plugin/v2.7.`**

Can someone please help me with the code for creating a similar app.

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId:   'XXXX',
            xfbml:    true,
            version: 'v2.7'
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js     = d.createElement(s);
        js.id  = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id))
            return;
        js     = d.createElement(s);
        js.id  = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.adpreview.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
</body>

<div class="fb-ad-preview-deprecated" data-creative="&#123;object_story_id: &quot;19292868552_10151567679603553&quot;&#125;" data-ad-account-id="XXXX" data-ad-format="MOBILE_FEED_STANDARD"></div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the ads preview plugin has now been deprecated you can query for all the ads by making a graph API call for act_/ads. You can then query for the preview for the apps for the given ads.

Answer (score 0):

For the graph api

```
/previews?ids=[ {adId}, {adId}, {adId} ]&ad_format=RIGHT_COLUMN_STANDARD&appsecret_proof={appsecret_proof}
```

This worked for me, but you need to build a list of `adIds`